# Group by device name, and then take average

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large excel file that looks like this:

```
Device ID                          PM     Adjusted_Time  
c9edef390ccb2caa4f42cc05743978c8   49     1/1/18 0:00
30ca1371f6f901f5569bcf373df8d219   56     1/1/18 0:01
cad7c3d7cebf6f6e88e01c43d5dc764d   105    1/1/18 0:01
cd5796a78e2871621c34d6dcdb44d366   103    1/1/18 0:01
...
```

There are 26 obscure device ID's, each with data for each minute of each hour of each day for the entire year. My goal is to first group together the data for the respective Device ID's, so that i have each device's data for the year, and then to use some aspect of `pd.groupby` to get the 24-hour average PM value.

So far I convert to a datetime:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('data2018-2020.xlxs'
df1['Adjusted_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Adjusted_Time'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

and now i am trying to use groupby but i am not sure what to do next. `df1.pd.groupby('Device ID')["PM2.5"]` gives the same data, but there is no indication of which Device it is.

```
Adjusted_Time
2018-01-01 05:27:40     49.715808
2018-01-01 05:28:06     56.286233
2018-01-01 05:28:25    105.642026
2018-01-01 05:28:26    103.245486
2018-01-01 05:30:41     98.328302
```

My ideal output would be

```
Device ID       PM       Adjusted_Time
device1         45        01-01-2018
device2         55        01-01-2018
device3         66        01-01-2018
```

and so on for each of the 26 devices. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide copy pastable input data and the coresponding output data. E.g. for 2 different devices, like 3 rows each. You can get sample data by using `df1.to_dict()` but you might want to filter it down to like 6 rows before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly convert the date with revised format code as follows:

```
df['Adjusted_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adjusted_Time'], format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Note that if your dates are actually with day first rather than month first, you can use:

```
df['Adjusted_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Adjusted_Time'], format = '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```

Then `groupby()` 2 fields: `Device ID` and also the date field only of `Adjusted_Time`:

```
df.groupby([df['Device ID'], df['Adjusted_Time'].dt.date])['PM'].mean().reset_index()
```